# "ti mancherai" vs. "mancherò"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

I know that saying "**ti mancherai**" means "**I'm going to [gonna] miss you**", but what is the difference betwen saying "**ti mancherai**" with "**mancherò**" to a collocutor? Indeed, the second one sounds more logical to use as missing one is the first singular person, moreover, can't we make it "**ti mancherò**" by adding the pronoun "**ti**" for the same meaning, but seems to yield an ossimoro ... I'm lost.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is notoriously confusing, because English and Italian use opposite sentence structures to describe the feeling of missing someone.

In English, this is rendered as a literal feeling. The subject of the sentence is the person who is feeling the absence of the other person. The other person is the object of this feeling.

In Italian, the focus is on the person that is absent: they are the subject of the sentence. We may conceptualise this as *being* (physically) missing. The person who is feeling this absence, on the other hand, is indicated with a *complemento di termine*: with the “a” preposition, or with *mi/ti/gli*…

*Mi mancherai* (*tu mancherai a me*) means “**I** will miss **you**”. Imagine that this literally translated “You will be away/absent/missing from me”.

*Ti mancherò* (*io mancherò a te*) is the opposite, so it means “You will miss me”.

**Ti mancherai* (**tu mancherai a te*) is usually meaningless in Italian, as it would translate as “you will miss yourself”.

*Mancherò* is meaningless if not accompanied with some extra information (*mancherò al lavoro*: I’ll be absent from work; *mancherò alla mamma*: mum will miss me).

Comment: Thank you so much Andrea. Btw, apart from this subject, Turkish is very similar to Italian for several idiomaticatal usages, I met really lots of them, just recalled the one which's "prendere decisione" is "karar almak" [-> "decisione+prendere" as ordered] , while it's "make a decision" in English.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan In Italian it would be “prendere una decisione” or “prendere la decisione”, depending on the context. Never without an article.

Comment: thanks @egreg , it's also similar from the point of view of [in]definite article : "karar almak==prendere una decisione", "karar**ı** almak=prendere la decisione", but as agglunative(as suffix).